# Atom editor install in Ubuntu 14.04. I've used these commands

Tags: ubuntu, installation, apt

I'm trying to install atom via the terminal in ubuntu 14.04 (on a Chromebook).

Here is what I've run

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/atom

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install atom

which atom

/usr/bin/atom

it appears to be installed but will not launch. The icon is in my directory and I can see a folder created but it will not work. Any advice? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone facing this beginner hurdle, I figured out that in Chromebook, the way to launch atom is from the terminal using a prompt like

```
~$ atom README.md
```

So instead of opening it from GUI interface, open a terminal session and launch it this way. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing from the actual package file released by the Atom team on GitHub?

If not, it may be worth a try. You can see the instructions on the Atom github page.

https://github.com/atom/atom

Also, have you tried opening Atom through the command line? the command should just be `atom`

Comment: The OP answered his own question half an hour before you posted this. As you can see, he did indeed solve the issue by launching Atom from the command line. Please read the other answers before posting a new one!

Answer (score 0):

Please note, the OP's commands are not the official way to install atom in Ubuntu. The official instruction is [here](https://flight-manual.atom.io/getting-started/sections/installing-atom/#platform-linux) (**info as of 6th Oct 2019**):

```
wget -qO - https://packagecloud.io/AtomEditor/atom/gpgkey | sudo apt-key add -
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://packagecloud.io/AtomEditor/atom/any/ any main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/atom.list'
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install atom
```